# Unable to start com.bitnami.mongodb

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine, bitnami, mongodb-replica-set

I'm using MongoDB with replication on azure and I have attached an SSD disk to MongoDB node and mounted on a specific path.
And I changed MongoDB data and logs path to specific path in MongoDB.conf(/opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf) file.
But when I restart MongoDB server using `sudo service bitnami restart` command it gives me error like

> ERROR Unable to start com.bitnami.mongodb: Cannot find pid file
>   '/opt/bitnami/mong...b.pid'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrrmY.png)

```
bitnami@mymongodb0:/tmp$ sudo service bitnami status
● bitnami.service - LSB: Bitnami Init Script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/bitnami)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-08-04 05:49:58 UTC; 2min 15s ago
  Process: 26654 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/bitnami stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 92099 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bitnami start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 04 05:46:53 mymongodb0 bitnami[92099]: 2017-08-04T05:46:53.376Z - info: Saving configuration info to disk
Aug 04 05:46:53 mymongodb0 bitnami[92099]: 2017-08-04T05:46:53.987Z - info: Performing service start operation for mongodb
Aug 04 05:49:58 mymongodb0 bitnami[92099]: nami    ERROR Unable to start com.bitnami.mongodb: Cannot find pid file '/opt/bitnami/mong...b.pid'.
Aug 04 05:49:58 mymongodb0 bitnami[92099]: 2017-08-04T05:49:58.249Z - error: Unable to perform start operation nami command exited wi... code 1
Aug 04 05:49:58 mymongodb0 systemd[1]: bitnami.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 04 05:49:58 mymongodb0 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bitnami Init Script.
Aug 04 05:49:58 mymongodb0 systemd[1]: Unit bitnami.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

root@mymongodb0:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        30G  1.8G   27G   7% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  8.4M  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdd1      1007G  272M  956G   1% /data
/dev/sdb1        32G   48M   30G   1% /mnt/resource
```

**/opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf**

```
# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
  #engine:
  #mmapv1:
    #smallFiles: true
  #wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /data/logs/mongodb.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  unixDomainSocket:
    enabled: true
    pathPrefix: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp

# replica set options
replication:
  replSetName: replicaset

# process management options
processManagement:
   fork: false
   pidFilePath: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb.pid

    /dev/sdc1        50G   33M   50G   1% /bitnami
    tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Do you check log in `/opt/bitnami/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log`?  I suggest you could `sudo service bitnami stop`, then `sudo service bitnami start`. If it works, please check mongodb process. Use `ps -ef|grep mongo`. `kill -9 <pid>`. Then start mongodb.

Comment: I suggest you had better check log firstly and ensure you have enough disk space.

Comment: When you change the data path do you stop mongodb?  Please show me the result `ps -ef|grep mongodb |grep -v grep`

Comment: No, grep mongodb not `-v`, `-v` means `select non-matching lines`

Comment: `root@mymongodb0:/home/bitnami# ps -ef|grep mongodb
root       1643   1519  0 06:19 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mongodb`

Comment: Hi, do you `chown mongo:mongo <new data path>` to new path?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT i have done that but still i'm getting an error `nami    ERROR Unable to start com.bitnami.mongodb: Cannot find pid file '/opt/bitnami/mong...db.pid`

Comment: Hi, do you test create this file? Please `chown mongo:mongo /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb.pid`.

Comment: Please `df -h`. Disk have enough space. If possible, you could share here.

Comment: If possible, could you show your mongodb.conf in your question or what you change.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I changed data and logs path  only

Comment: You sure you give permission to `/data`. `chown mongo:mongo -R /data`. I test in my lab, I don't meet your error log.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much @Walter-MSFT for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long talk, the root reason is `/data` not give enough permissions.

```
chown mongo:mongo -R /data
```

`/data` directory needs `mongo` user and group.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up for an older image: **bitnami/mongodb:3.2.7-r5**

I mounted a directory /Users/sb/mongodata on my host to `:/bitnami/mongodb` and had to manually create this directory structure:

```
- conf
  mongodb.conf 
- data
   - db
- logs
- tmp
```

Then `chmod -R g+rwX /Users/sb/mongodata`